# In Mysql 5.5, why is the upper bound of a character range not inclusive?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

So I'm trying to query on a character range, i.e. all manufacturers with names starting with a or b:

```
SELECT manufacturer FROM warehouse WHERE manufacturer >= 'a' AND manufacturer <= 'b'
```

or:

```
SELECT manufacturer FROM warehouse WHERE manufacturer BETWEEN 'a' and 'b'
```

For both of these queries, I only get back manus with names starting with a. If I changed the range to a-c, I would get back all with a-b. Why is the upper bound of the range not inclusive? My main issue with this is how can I include all 'Z's in the range. A-Z would not include any z's in this case.

The manual here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between
... seems pretty self explanatory. Unfortunately things are not working the way they should.

The weird part is, this works when I create a small test table. However it does not work properly on my 15 million row table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try [**REGEXP**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html) with the [**BINARY**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-binary-op.html) operator

```
SELECT manufacturer FROM warehouse
WHERE manufacturer REGEXP BINARY '^[ab]';
```

if you want a range (say from `A-M`)

```
SELECT manufacturer FROM warehouse
WHERE manufacturer REGEXP BINARY '^[A-M]';
```

case sensitivity ranges

```
SELECT manufacturer FROM warehouse
WHERE manufacturer REGEXP BINARY '^[A-Ma-m]';
```

Notice I used the `^` regular expression operator. This searches "from the beginning of the string".

As for your question, why does `BETWEEN 'a' and 'b'` fail to get all b's?

Look at what you are asking for in the query: Every manu that is >= 'a' and <= 'b'.

- Does 'a' return?. If you have a manu named 'a', then yes.
- Does 'aa' return?. If you have a manu named 'a', then yes.
- Does 'azzzzzzzzzzzzzzz' return?. I think you know the answer to this one.
- Does 'b' return?. If you have a manu named 'b', then yes.
- Does 'ba' return?. Even if you had a manu named 'ba', then no.

Although inefficient, here is a query that would have worked:

```
SELECT manufacturer FROM warehouse
WHERE LEFT(manufacturer,1) IN ('a','b');
```

## UPDATE 2013-02-11 15:22 EDT

I have a nice suggestion: Create an index that only stores two characters of `manufacturer`.

Perhaps this:

```
ALTER TABLE manufacturer 
ADD INDEX manufacturer_prefix (manufacturer(2));
```

If you have any index of the entire `manufacturer` field, drop that index. You can then do effective two-character range searches.

Comment: that works - even without the binary casting. since our manufacturer names are more than just two characters - ie. 'lucent', we read somewhere that mysql considers 'lucent' to be greater than 'lu' thus the range does not work as expected.

Comment: I see your update, we may try that. What works now and is actually slightly faster than our old way with the between ranges:
    WHERE part_manufacturer_clean LIKE 'aa%'  
    OR part_manufacturer_clean LIKE 'ab%' 
    OR part_manufacturer_clean LIKE 'ac%'

vs old:
    WHERE part_manufacturer_clean BETWEEN 'aa' AND 'ad'

Comment: @Brett: ***"we read somewhere that mysql considers 'lucent' to be greater than 'lu'"*** That's how it works, in all SQL flavours, not only in MySQL. That's how it works in dictionaries, too. "lucent" is after "lu" in most of them.

Comment: ypercube's comment is worth repeating: just think how it would look like in a dictionary. This really answers your initial question.